# Is there any existing postgis package for Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) compiled against GDAL 2.0+?

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal, linux

I stumbled upon [this](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8073#note-12) error while using QGIS (2.18.13) to display a PostGIS raster and read in comment #14 on the same issue, that it is working when using a newer GDAL version.

I have GDAL 1.11.3 used by the DB, which I installed using [this](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS23UbuntuPGSQL96Apt) instruction (PostgreSQL 9.6.5 & PostGIS 2.3.3). I am curious, if anyone has a PostGIS package for Ubuntu 16.04 compiled against a newer GDAL version. Or do I need to compile it from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ubuntu GIS team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has GDAL 2.2.1 for Xenial and has PostGIS 2.3.3 compiled against it. From the [PostGIS build logs](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/305074287/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.postgis_2.3.2+dfsg-1~xenial0_BUILDING.txt.gz)

```
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking GDAL version... 2.1.3
```

Install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install postgis;
```

EDIT by OP:

I have tried ubuntugis before and it didn't work, because I used the newest PostgreSQL version (9.6) from the Postgresql repository, but as it turns out, the current ubuntugis-unstable PostGIS version is compiled against PostgreSQL 9.5. So I removed the Postgresql repository from my `sources.list` and did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3 postgresql-contrib-9.5 postgresql-9.5-postgis-scripts
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

That did the trick for me, just to give a little more context.

Comment: There may be newer versions in the unstable: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=xenial

Comment: @user30184 I didn't even see that, I blame Launchpad's interface, I didn't realize the package list was paged. Yuck.

Comment: @EvanCarroll please update the link and install part of your answer to the unstable ppa.

Comment: @AndreJ why? the one I linked is the one I cited in my answer from the Ubuntu GIS ppa.

Comment: Yep, that makes 100% more sense.

Comment: Indeed, and you need unstable for QGIS too.